# Remove all text, character before first bracket and after last bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

My string :

`var string = '.,.a,,{Correct Answer Nr.1 : b.) Susan },{Correct Answer Nr.3 : b.) She doesn’t say },.x.b,'`

How can i remove all text, character before first { and after last }?

My desired result :

`{Correct Answer Nr.1 : b.) Susan },{Correct Answer Nr.3 : b.) She doesn’t say }`

and remove : `.,.a,, and ,.x.b,`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following regex replacement:

```js
var string = '.,.a,,{Correct Answer Nr.1 : b.) Susan },{Correct Answer Nr.3 : b.) She doesn’t say },.x.b,';
var output = string.replace(/^[^{]+|[^}]+$/g, "");
console.log(output);
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `[^{]+` match one or more leading characters which are not `{`
- `|` OR
- `[^}]+` match one or more trailing characters which are not `}`
- `$` at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

By greedy behaviour, pattern

```
{.*}
```

matches

```
{Correct Answer Nr.1 : b.) Susan },{Correct Answer Nr.3 : b.) She doesn’t say }
```